# Is this how to find lambda when using the method of separation of variables with inhomogeneous boundary conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have $$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0, 0 \le x,y \le 1 \\ \cases{u(0,y) = y \\ u(1,y) = 1+y \\ u(x,0) = x \\ u(x,1) = 1+x}$$

Using method of separation of variables we plug in a trial solution of the form $u(x,y) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$. After doing so, I arrive to the following ODEs:

$$\phi(x)''-\lambda \phi(x) = 0 \\ \phi(y)''+\lambda \phi(y) = 0$$

The solutions to which I have arrived to:

$$\phi(x) = A\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}x) \\ \phi(y) = C\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}y)+D\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}y)$$

Now we're at the step for solving for $\lambda$. If I'm not mistaken, since $\lambda$ is the same for both ODEs, we only need to solve it using 1 of the 2 ODEs instead of both, and I see a path for obtaining that for $\phi(y)$. So if this is correct, starting with $\phi(y)$ we get:
$$\phi(y=0) = x = C \\ \phi(y=1) = 1+x = x + D\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}) \\ 
\text{and we'll assume D is arbitrary and that } D \ne 0\text{ so to keep it simple, I'll say } D = 1 \\ 1 = \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}) \\ 
\text{and that would give us: } \sqrt{\lambda} = \frac{\pi(1+4n)}{2L}$$

Comment: Firstly the functions of $x$ and $y$ are different, so you should not give them the same name $\phi$.  Secondly, no - the boundary conditions used in a separation of variables argument must be homogeneous, so that the superposition of solutions also satisfies the same conditions.  This is notwithstanding your error of assuming $\phi$ is a function of $y$ only, then introducing $x$ dependence via a boundary condition.

Comment: @messenger Thank you for elucidating me on this. You're correct, we do need homogeneity for superposition to work. I would need to split up the problem into 4 separate problems such that homogeneity is satisfied along either x or y and then provide the inhomogeneous solution to 1 side of the boundary. The solutions yielded in all 4 of these cases can then be summed into a single solution via superposition

Comment: You can split it into two separate problems - one of which has homogeneous conditions in the $x$-direction, and one which has homogeneous conditions in the $y$-direction.

Comment: @messenger So it would be inhomogeneous on both sides of the corresponding direction to get 2 parts and set up the same case for the corresponding directions? You'll have to help me understand what that would look like. So I'm guessing for $\phi(y)''-\lambda \phi(y) = 0$ we get $\phi(y) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda}y} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}y}$ and we would plug this into $u(x,y) = \sum_n a_n\phi(x)\phi(y)$ and I'd plug in for the 2 inhomogeneous BCs 1-by-1. The constants c_1 and c_2 would be absorbed into $a_n$

Comment: @messenger regardless, I'll have to look into that simpler method on my own time. For now, I've effectively solved the problem using 4 parts, now I just need to deal with the values at the corners. I just posted the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825019/quick-question-about-boundary-conditions-at-the-corners-of-the-boundary-on-a-rec) if you're interested. Thanks again for the insight