# Is some information about the solution typically lost when solving a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To narrow down the question a bit, I'm talking about PDEs subjected to inhomogeneous BCs.

Suppose we have a problem such that: $$Lu(x,y) = 0| 0\le x,y \le L \\ \cases{u(x,0) = 0 \\ u(x,L) = L+x \\u(0,y) = 0 \\ u(L,y)=0}$$

Where L is the linear differential operator.

When L was a Laplacian, I used method of separation of variables, the solution satisfies $u(x,0) = L+x$ for every point except at the corners I consistently got $u(0,0) = u(L,0) = 0$ when it should be L and 2L, respectively. Is this an issue that occurs in general when solving PDEs (subjected to inhomogeneous BCs)?

A yes or no answer is fine, this question is more of a sanity check.

---

Edit:

So the original problem had BCs:

$$\cases{u(x,0) = x \\ u(x,L) = L+x \\ u(0,y) = y \\ u(L,y) = L+y}$$

And the example I provided is 1 of 4 different problems that come from applying each inhomogeneous boundary while having the remaining boundaries be homogeneous to allow for the usage of eigenfunctions.

Comment: According to the first BC, $u(0,0)=L$ and $u(L,0)=2L$, but according to the third and fourth BCs, $u(0,0)=0$ and $u(L,0)=0$, respectively. Therefore, the solution to the PDE will necessarily be discontinuous at those corners.

Comment: @Gonçalo Made a slight edit. And yes! I suppose that's right, the BCs along x would contradict that outcome at those points because those points also fall within the 3rd and 4th BC, not just the first (or second rather). So where the boundaries intersect there is a contradiction that I need to overcome somehow. I also need them to remain homogeneous to allow for the usage of eigenfunctions which presents another problem.

Comment: @Gonçalo I guess if I were to rewrite the BCs they would look more like $$u(x,0) = 0 \\ u(x,L) = x+L \\ u(0,0 < y < L) = 0 \\ u(L, 0<y<L) = 0$$ or something like that. Don't know if I'm allowed to do that or what it would look like if I implemented it, but that's the first thing that came to mind for trying to get around it. Either way, thank you for helping me pinpoint the problem

Comment: If you write $u(x,y)=v(x,y)+x+y$, all boundary conditions for $v$ are homogeneous. This may solve the problem.

Comment: @Gonçalo Sorry, I should have clarified my motivation here, I actually built the problem using that solution, x+y, so I have no doubt that would work, I just wanted to use methods like the aforementioned one to arrive to that solution.

Comment: @Gonçalo I tried a couple different things and wasn't able to resolve a solution other than just explicitly defining the values at these points. I think I'll just accept that using eigenfunctions is going to result in information being lost at the vertices of a boundary. I'd imagine this wouldn't be an issue in a circular domain in polar coordinates due to a lack of vertices.

Comment: @Gonçalo I posted an image in my question [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825019/quick-question-about-boundary-conditions-at-the-corners-of-the-boundary-on-a-rec) so you can visualize exactly what the problem looks like. Thanks again for the help!